# How to prevent Scrapy Shell from redirecting

Tags: response.redirect, scrapy-shell

I am trying to scrape data from a search query in Lulu and Georgia's website. This is the link to the search query when I searched up "desks": https://www.luluandgeorgia.com/catalogsearch/result/?indexName=magento_en_products&facetsFilter=&page=0&numericFilters=

However, when I use the scrapy shell with that link and try to extract images of the products, it is extracting images from the main web page, meaning that using that link redirects the website to its main home page. To prevent this redirect, I went into Shell.py and made redirect = False wherever I could. However this is not working and the shell continues to scrape information from the main home page. What else can I do to prevent this?